# Rendering a background using bigvideo.js within a Rails application

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, video

I have the following implementation of bigvideo.js functioning perfectly outside of my Rails project.

```
<script src="modernizr.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/3.0/video.js"></script>
<!-- BigVideo -->
<script src="bigvideo.js"></script>

<script>
var BV = new $.BigVideo();
BV.init();
if (Modernizr.touch) {
BV.show('yay.jpg');
 } else {
BV.show('test.mp4',{ambient:true});
 }
</script>
```

However, when I try to translate this to Rails, it will not render either the image or the video.
- I have all javascript files in assets/javascripts.  They appear to be pulling correctly. 
- Application.js is untouched and includes //= require_tree . 
- For the custom JS (the one where the js code is displayed above) I currently have it as a JS file in assets/javascripts.  I've tried putting the relevant image/video files in the folder with it, changing the paths to web addresses for the files, and naming it .html.erb and using ruby snippets, all with no success.

How can I make my implementation work?  You can see it working outside of Rails [here](http://itsplatonic.com/OnePager).

Comment: where yay.jpg and test.mp4 are?

Comment: As mentioned, I've tried putting the files in the same directory (assets/javascripts), I've tried uploading those files and then referring to them by url, and I've tried putting them in the relevant rails assets folder and using ruby snippets to refer to them.  None have been successful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get BigVideo to work with rails. I'm not sure if this is the most ideal fix, but if you give the full url for the video (via something like `<%= request.protocol + request.host_with_port + asset_path('main-video.mp4') %>`) it will load on the page.

So the code I ended up using in the end was:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
        var BV = new $.BigVideo();
  BV.init();
  BV.show("<%= request.protocol + request.host_with_port + asset_path('main-video.mp4') %>",{ambient:true});
  });
</script>
```

I've set up an example app that you can take a look at. It's located here (note: I tried to remain *somewhat* faithful to your onepager example, but it's not exactly the same):

http://bigvideo.herokuapp.com/

You can also see the code I used to create it here:

https://github.com/scouttyg/bigvideo-example

I also did some fun stuff like put the video in its own directory (assets/videos), and added the precompiled paths to `application.rb` as well.

I think the idea is in general, you should use BigVideo with a CDN and not serve it up from the rails app itself -- similar to why it's suggested in rails to offload file uploading to things like S3, etc.

Comment: Can I ask what video editor you used to combine clips?  I'm creating a similar thing to your example, but each time I combine clips bigvideo renders the beginning of the video very pixilated before correcting itself.

Comment: I didn't create the video, I used the video from the source code from your onepager here: http://itsplatonic.com/OnePager/ (line 79). Can't help you there unfortunately!

Comment: Haha.  Wish I could delete that comment... Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

if js working properly your files would render properly in case you put them into `app/assets/images` directory and include them into js like below

```
BV.show('assets/yay.jpg');
  } else {
BV.show('assets/test.mp4',{ambient:true});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that implementation does not display either.

Comment: The JS works outside of Rails.  Within Rails, all I've been able to verify is that the files appear to be pulling correctly (using 'view source' on chrome).

Comment: if you can render not js itself but js.erb, or js is inside html.erb, than try to use `<%= asset_path 'yay.jpg' %>`

Comment: other observation is you do not have `$(function() {[your js]});` wrapper for your js... (according to initial setup snippet here http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/)

Comment: given that pointing to a web hosted file (rather than local) does not work, I don't think the asset path is the problem, but rather the configuration within rails of assets/javascripts.

i did try inserting the wrapper.  not sure what function it would have (it was not used in the non-rails version which functioned well).

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

Add these (required) lines of code to your application.html.erb file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/video.js/5.11.3/video.js">  </script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/BigVideo.js/1.1.5/lib/bigvideo.js"></script>
```

and then the code Scott included above

```
<script>
$(function() {
var BV = new $.BigVideo();
BV.init();
BV.show("<%= request.protocol + request.host_with_port + asset_path('main-video.mp4') %>",{ambient:true});
});
</script>
```

...and then eventually decide to do it a better way, because this will get things working at the very very least.