# Background Image on Machines Bigvideo.js Does Not Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, video, video.js

I'm running bigvideo.js on my webpage, with the set-up provided here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17581187/1318135).

I'd like the have a background image display when bigvideo.js is incompatible with a user's set-up (scripts disabled, old browser, etc.) but the javascript overrides all attempts to add a background in the html/css.

How can I implement one?  Right now it defaults to a black background.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, but I used css to set a background image:

```
#video{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url('/video/img/first.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Then just like normal:

```
$(function() {
    var BV = new $.BigVideo({controls:false,
                              container:$('#video')});
    BV.init();
    BV.show('/video/video/764116.mp4');
});
```

To get a png of the first frame you can use VLC (Video -> Take snapshot).