# Javascript URL Navigation Handling Interfering with other Javascript Sections

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, video.js

Two aspects of my project's Javascript are interfering with each other.  Not sure why, or how to resolve.

I have the following in my code, in order to allow for a URL hashtag action:

```
function getHashValue(key) {
  return location.hash.match(new RegExp(key+'=([^&]*)'))[1];
}

var hash = getHashValue('hash');

console.log(hash);
```

I'm also running video.js and bigvideo.js within my Rails project.  For some reason, the javascript code above prevents the other javascript (my bigvideo implementation) from functioning.  Why?  How do I resolve?

My bigvideo implementation is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17581187/1318135

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems possible that getHashValue is throwing an exception (array limit exceeded?) which could interfere prevent other code on the thread from running. Try enclosing the return statement in a try/catch.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you get: TypeError (exception) Cannot read property '1' of null.
Catch the exception and you'll be okay, I think.